# How to show all (-Wall) warnings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ extension. IntelliSense  shows some errors but definitely not all of them, I tried settings the following setting:

```
"C_Cpp.default.compilerArgs": ["${default}", "-Wall"]
```

But is has no effect. The only thing that's some improvement is adding a build task: when I run it the warnings and errors it generates are displayed inline in VSCode. This workaround is still suboptimal: I need to build to get the errors while I would like to get as soon as I finish typing them (like it already is the case for other errors both in VSCode and other editors I know).

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You can try the clangd extension.